# Android progress diologue not showing until async task complete

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have two `asynctask` and second one was call in `onPostExecute()` of first `asynctask`. I want to show progress dialog until both the two `asynctask` completes. Problem is that my `progressdialog` showing only for some millisecond and then hide. How can I solve this ?

```
//TO call web service save Data on Server
    class async_SaveData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            showDialog();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespacegetlistdata, method_name__getlistdata);

            cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from FieldTestDataFinal Where isSend ='N'", null);
            /*for(int i=0; i<cursor.getCount(); i++)
            {*/
            int k = 0;
            try {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    /*while (cursor.moveToNext())*/
                    do {

                        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

                        jsonObject.put("ConsAcNo", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CONS_ACCOUNT_NO")));
                        jsonObject.put("MeterSrNo", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("MTR_SERIAL_NO")));

                        //arr.put(jsonObject);

                        //request.properties.clear();
                        if (k == 0) {
                            request.addProperty(parameter_getlistdata, jsonObject.toString());//add the parameters
                            request.addProperty(parameter_getlistdata1, "XXMFU_APP_INSERTFIELDDATA");//add the parameters
                        } else {
                            request.setProperty(0, jsonObject.toString());//add the parameters
                            request.setProperty(1, "XXMFU_APP_INSERTFIELDDATA");//add the parameters
                        }
                        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);//set soap version
                        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                        envelope.dotNet = true;
                        try {
                            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url_getlistdata);
                            androidHttpTransport.call(soap_action_getlistdata, envelope);  // this is the actual part that will call the webservice
                            //SoapPrimitive prim = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();  // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
                            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.d("myError -", String.valueOf(e));
                        }
                        k++;
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
                cursor.close();


            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            // }

            return resultSaveAllData;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result1) {

            new async_SaveImage().execute();

            super.onPostExecute(result1);

        }
    }






 //TO call web service save Image on Server
        class async_SaveImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespacegetlistdata, method_name__image);

                cursorImage = db.rawQuery("select * from FieldTestDataFinal Where isSend ='N'", null);
                /*for(int i=0; i<cursor.getCount(); i++)
                {*/
                int k = 0;
                try {
                    if (cursorImage.moveToFirst()) {

                        /*while (cursor.moveToNext())*/
                        do {
                            //request.properties.clear();

                            if (k == 0) {
                                request.addProperty("fileByte1", cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("METER_IMAGE1")));//add the parameters
                                request.addProperty("fileName1", cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("fileName1")));//add the parameters

                            } else {
                                request.setProperty(0, cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("METER_IMAGE1")));//add the parameters
                                request.setProperty(1, cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("fileName1")));//add the parameters

                            }
                            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);//set soap version
                            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                            envelope.dotNet = true;
                            try {
                                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url_getlistdata);
                                 androidHttpTransport.call(soap_action_uploadImage, envelope);  // this is the actual part that will call the webservice
                                //SoapPrimitive prim = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();  // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
                                SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.d("myError -", String.valueOf(e));
                            }
                            k++;

                        } while (cursorImage.moveToNext());

                        db.execSQL("UPDATE FieldTestDataFinal SET isSend='Y' WHERE isSend='N'");

                    }
                    cursorImage.close();


                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
                // }

                return resultSaveAllData;

            }

@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result1) {

            hideDialog();
            super.onPostExecute(result1);

        }
    }
```

Comment: If both the tasks should run at the same time, then why don't you make a single asynctask?

Comment: show Process Dialog on first  asynctask's pre execute and dismiss it on second's post execute

Comment: I have different web service for both async task and i want to execute both one after second.

Comment: Thanks Himani. I have done same as you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

I have moved both the tasks in single `AsyncTask`. First `saveData()` will be executed followed by `saveImage()`. Check it out:

```
class async_SaveData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            showDialog();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            saveData();
            saveImage();
            // You are not using returned parameter in onPostExecute(). So, I am passing empty string
            return "";

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result1) {

            super.onPostExecute(result1);

        }

               public void saveData()
        {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespacegetlistdata, method_name__getlistdata);
            cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from FieldTestDataFinal Where isSend ='N'", null);
                /*for(int i=0; i<cursor.getCount(); i++)
                {*/
            int k = 0;
            try
            {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst())
                {
                        /*while (cursor.moveToNext())*/
                    do
                    {
                        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

                        jsonObject.put("ConsAcNo", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CONS_ACCOUNT_NO")));
                        jsonObject.put("MeterSrNo", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("MTR_SERIAL_NO")));

                        //arr.put(jsonObject);

                        //request.properties.clear();
                        if (k == 0)
                        {
                            request.addProperty(parameter_getlistdata, jsonObject.toString());//add the parameters
                            request.addProperty(parameter_getlistdata1, "XXMFU_APP_INSERTFIELDDATA");//add the parameters
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            request.setProperty(0, jsonObject.toString());//add the parameters
                            request.setProperty(1, "XXMFU_APP_INSERTFIELDDATA");//add the parameters
                        }
                        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);//set soap version
                        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                        envelope.dotNet = true;
                        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url_getlistdata);
                        androidHttpTransport.call(soap_action_getlistdata, envelope);  // this is the actual part that will call the webservice
                        //SoapPrimitive prim = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();  // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
                        SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

                        k++;
                    }
                    while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
                cursor.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("myError -", String.valueOf(e));
            }
            // }

            return resultSaveAllData;
        }

        public void saveImage()
        {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespacegetlistdata, method_name__image);
            cursorImage = db.rawQuery("select * from FieldTestDataFinal Where isSend ='N'", null);
                    /*for(int i=0; i<cursor.getCount(); i++)
                    {*/
            int k = 0;
            try
            {
                if (cursorImage.moveToFirst())
                {

                            /*while (cursor.moveToNext())*/
                    do
                    {
                        //request.properties.clear();

                        if (k == 0)
                        {
                            request.addProperty("fileByte1", cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("METER_IMAGE1")));//add the parameters
                            request.addProperty("fileName1", cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("fileName1")));//add the parameters

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            request.setProperty(0, cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("METER_IMAGE1")));//add the parameters
                            request.setProperty(1, cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("fileName1")));//add the parameters

                        }
                        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);//set soap version
                        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                        envelope.dotNet = true;

                        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url_getlistdata);
                        androidHttpTransport.call(soap_action_uploadImage, envelope);  // this is the actual part that will call the webservice
                        //SoapPrimitive prim = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();  // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
                        SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

                        k++;

                    }
                    while (cursorImage.moveToNext());

                    db.execSQL("UPDATE FieldTestDataFinal SET isSend='Y' WHERE isSend='N'");

                }
                cursorImage.close();


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("myError -", String.valueOf(e));
            }
            // }

            return resultSaveAllData;
        }
}
```

Comment: Hey, Still it is showing for less then one second. This is not solved my issue.

Comment: @MoinKhan Check how much time onBackground() execution takes. May be exception is occurring in the methods. Write `e.printstacktrace()` inside catch block of both the methods.

Comment: Async task successfully saving data on my server. I have 10 images in my sqlite database so it takes 1 or 2 minutes to upload image on server. But my process dialogue showing only for less then  one second. I want to show dialog untill all the images save on server.

Comment: @MoinKhan I've updated the code, check for execeptions.

Comment: @MoinKhan And the HttpTransportSE call you are making, is Synchronous or Asynchronous ?

Comment: I debug code and i realize that when doInBackground called then dialog hide.

Answer (score 0):

put your progress dialog in also second asynctask's OnpreExecute() and dismiss both dialog in postExceute:

```
//TO call web service save Data on Server
class async_SaveData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        showDialog();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespacegetlistdata, method_name__getlistdata);

        cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from FieldTestDataFinal Where isSend ='N'", null);
        /*for(int i=0; i<cursor.getCount(); i++)
        {*/
        int k = 0;
        try {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                /*while (cursor.moveToNext())*/
                do {

                    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

                    jsonObject.put("ConsAcNo", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CONS_ACCOUNT_NO")));
                    jsonObject.put("MeterSrNo", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("MTR_SERIAL_NO")));

                    //arr.put(jsonObject);

                    //request.properties.clear();
                    if (k == 0) {
                        request.addProperty(parameter_getlistdata, jsonObject.toString());//add the parameters
                        request.addProperty(parameter_getlistdata1, "XXMFU_APP_INSERTFIELDDATA");//add the parameters
                    } else {
                        request.setProperty(0, jsonObject.toString());//add the parameters
                        request.setProperty(1, "XXMFU_APP_INSERTFIELDDATA");//add the parameters
                    }
                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);//set soap version
                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                    envelope.dotNet = true;
                    try {
                        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url_getlistdata);
                        androidHttpTransport.call(soap_action_getlistdata, envelope);  // this is the actual part that will call the webservice
                        //SoapPrimitive prim = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();  // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
                        SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d("myError -", String.valueOf(e));
                    }
                    k++;
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();


        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        // }

        return resultSaveAllData;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result1) {

        new async_SaveImage().execute();

        super.onPostExecute(result1);

    }
}






//TO call web service save Image on Server
    class async_SaveImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        showDialog();
    }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespacegetlistdata, method_name__image);

            cursorImage = db.rawQuery("select * from FieldTestDataFinal Where isSend ='N'", null);
            /*for(int i=0; i<cursor.getCount(); i++)
            {*/
            int k = 0;
            try {
                if (cursorImage.moveToFirst()) {

                    /*while (cursor.moveToNext())*/
                    do {
                        //request.properties.clear();

                        if (k == 0) {
                            request.addProperty("fileByte1", cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("METER_IMAGE1")));//add the parameters
                            request.addProperty("fileName1", cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("fileName1")));//add the parameters

                        } else {
                            request.setProperty(0, cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("METER_IMAGE1")));//add the parameters
                            request.setProperty(1, cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("fileName1")));//add the parameters

                        }
                        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);//set soap version
                        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                        envelope.dotNet = true;
                        try {
                            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url_getlistdata);
                             androidHttpTransport.call(soap_action_uploadImage, envelope);  // this is the actual part that will call the webservice
                            //SoapPrimitive prim = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();  // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
                            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.d("myError -", String.valueOf(e));
                        }
                        k++;

                    } while (cursorImage.moveToNext());

                    db.execSQL("UPDATE FieldTestDataFinal SET isSend='Y' WHERE isSend='N'");

                }
                cursorImage.close();


            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            // }

            return resultSaveAllData;

        }

  @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result1) {

        hideDialog();
        super.onPostExecute(result1);

    }
}
```